# Number of query values and destination fields are not the same in ms access

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I am trying to execute this sql insert statement below but encountered an error which is listed below. Would appreciate some advise, thanks.

```
 public void addSale(String saleDetails, String saleTotal) 
                        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

     Statement myStatement = getConnection();
     String sql = "INSERT INTO Sale (SaleDetails, SaleTotal) VALUES ('"+saleDetails+"','"+saleTotal+"')";

     myStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
     closeConnection();
  } 
}
```

Error:

Java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3109)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:337)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:287)

Here's the design view on ms-access:

[image]

Comment: You might have a quote or something in the salesDetails variable.  Consider using a prepared statement.  Besides avoiding this kind of error, they're safer.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `System.out.println(sql);` or use your logging framework and try that statement directly within access. It's possible that you have problems with the different data types over odbc. Otherwise the statement looks fine for me.

Maybe your variables contains `'` and/or commas. That may cause problems as well if they aren't escaped. You should consider using paramenter binding.

Answer (score 0):

I think your insert should be:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Sale (SaleDetails, SaleTotal) VALUES (" + saleDetails + ", " + saleTotal + ")";
```

Also, you may need to convert saleTotal from a string to a number before doing the insert.

Comment: Hi James, SaleDetails is a text/memo data type and needs to be quoted and any single quotes need to be replaced with two single quotes, but SaleTotal is a number, as you note, and does not need quotes. Ideally, the OP should use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of comma as a decimal separator on your system. value1 is 2.5 and value2 is  3.2 but you got 2,5,3,2 (you hope 2.5,3.2)